# How to arrange dockingable views at the first start of the program. AvalonDock

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

At start of the program I always see my `FeatureViewTemplate` is shown at the right side within `FileStatsViewTemplate` like that:
[image]

But I would like the arrange of areas to be in such order `File Stats` at the left side and the `FeatureArea` at the right side. Like that: 
[image]

**How to do such arrange of `FileStats` and `FeatureArea` at the first start of the program** (***when there is no "AvalonDock.config" file created by program ***)? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to add two LayoutAnchorablePane and one LayoutDocumentPane.

```
 <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
    <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane Name="FirstAnchorablePane"/>
      <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane/>
      <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane Name="SecondAnchorablePane"/>
    </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
  </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
```

Correspondingly in LayoutInitializer initialize the two anchorable panes with the corresponding content.

```
        var item = anchorableToShow.Content; 
        var toolsPane = layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutAnchorablePane>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "SecondAnchorablePane");
        var firstPane = layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutAnchorablePane>().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == "FirstAnchorablePane");
        if (toolsPane != null)
        {
            if(item is RecentFilesViewModel)
                toolsPane.Children.Add(anchorableToShow);
            if (item is FileStatsViewModel)
                firstPane.Children.Add(anchorableToShow);
            return true;
        }
```

But with only one LayoutAnchorablePane, maybe there is a way to do so. No idea at all, would be interesting to know too.